# What is the purpose of the file "drawables.xml" under the "values" directory?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable

For an android studio project, I found a file named "drawables.xml" in the "values" folder

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item name="ic_menu_camera" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_gallery" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_slideshow" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_manage" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_share" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share</item>
    <item name="ic_menu_send" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_send</item>
</resources>
```

What's the purpose of this file? Why does it create another reference to an existing drawable and why not just use "@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It may be that the developer had a bit of future-proofing in mind.

The developer could have had Java code reference `android.R.drawable.ic_menu_camera` and have layouts or other things reference `@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera`. However, if at some later point, the developer needed to switch from using a platform drawable to a custom one, then all of those references would need to be changed.

The drawable aliases set up in this file allow Java code to reference `R.drawable.ic_menu_camera` and layouts and other things reference `@drawable/ic_menu_camera`. Right now, the aliases indicate that those drawables "redirect" to platform drawables. However, at some time in the future, the developer could add a custom `ic_menu_camera` drawable, remove the alias... and nothing else needs to change in the Java code, layouts, etc.

Few apps refer to platform drawables, and so you will not see this sort of trick used most of the time. But, for cases where apps do refer to platform resources, this aliasing approach can reduce long-term maintenance.

FWIW, I cover this more in [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/08/22/platform-resource-aliases.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is very useful for whitelabeling.  So e.g., your main app can use one drawable but a whitelabel could use another but your code can reference the drawable using a single reference.

Answer (score 1):

Well In my opinion this file is useless because you already have the drawable file names.